# How to write to data files in executable created with pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.5, pyinstaller

I'm making onefile executables with pyinstaller on windows 10. I'm including data files (pickle files) by editing the .spec file...

How can I store changes made to these files during run time? My understanding is that the data files are copied to a temp directory during execution. I can read from the files using the path I get from sys._MEIPASS but the changes I write are lost after restarting the program.

Is there a way to write to pickle files stored inside the exe?

Comment: You cannot alter the executable.

Comment: To save changes to the pickle file inside the executable, choose one of two approaches:

1. **Use a Separate Directory for Runtime Data:**
    Create a separate directory, such as `sys._MEIPASS` or the user directory, to store writable data. Read the pickle file from the extraction location, modify it in the runtime directory, and save the changes there.

2. **Use Configuration File or Database:**
    If the data is more complex, consider using configuration files (JSON, YAML) or a lightweight database (SQLite) for data management flexibility at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))` instead of `sys._MEIPASS` to get the file path. While `sys._MEIPASS` points to a temporary directory with copied files during execution, `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))` gives the path to the directory containing the executable script itself. By modifying the path location to the *actual place of data files* you will be able to write to them.

Code example:

```
import os
import sys

# Get the directory containing the executable script or main Python file.
base_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))

# If it is executable in the dist/ remove the dist directory so that the path would be the same, 
# whether it is run by executable or by main Python file.
if os.path.basename(base_path) == 'dist':
    base_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(base_path, os.pardir))

# Assuming your pickle file is named 'data.pkl'
pickle_file_path = os.path.join(base_path, 'data.pkl')

# Modify the data as needed
with open(pickle_file_path, 'wb') as file:
    pass
```

Keep in mind that this way the executable file should always stay in the dist directory in which it is initially created. Create a shortcut if the executable file is needed in other locations.